# not able to read string after reading double data type

Tags: c

I am trying a c program with following input.

```
6
7.0
How are you
```

I am able to read and print the integer and double datatype variable but string variable is not accepting any input from user and printing the integer variable value by itself

Code for `int`:

```c
int j;
double e;
char str[100];

printf("enter the integer variable :");
scanf("%d", &j);
printf("enter the double variable :");
scanf("%lf", &e);
printf("enter the string :");
scanf("%[^\n]s",str);
printf("integer variable is %d\n",j);
printf("float variable is %0.1f\n",e);
printf("string variable is %s\n", str);
```

Output:

```
enter the integer :3
enter the double :4.0
enter the string :integer variable is 3 -> (automatically accepting printf of integer case and exiting the code)
float variable is 4.0
string variable is ??LX?
```

But If I am reading string value first (before reading integer and double) then code is working fine.

Code for `string`:

```c
printf("enter the string :");
scanf("%[^\n]s",str);
printf("enter the integer variable :");
scanf("%d", &j);
printf("enter the double variable :");
scanf("%lf", &e);
printf("integer variable id %d\n",j);
printf("float variable is %0.1f\n",e);
printf("string variable is %s\n", str);
```

Output:

```
enter the string :how are you
enter the integer :6
enter the double :7.0
integer variable is 3
float variable is 4.0
string variable is how are you
```

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]s",str);` --> `scanf(" %99[^\n]", str);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a space before the conversion format in `scanf()`:

```
scanf(" %99[^\n]", str);  // skip whitespace and read up to 99 characters on a line
```

This will instruct `scanf()` to skip the pending newline sitting in the `stdin` buffer, as well as any leading spaces in the next line.  As a matter of fact, it will keep reading lines until the user types a non empty one or the end of file is reached.  You should test the return value of `scanf()` to verify if `scanf()` succeeded.

Furthermore, you must tell `scanf()` the maximum number of characters to store into `str` otherwise a sufficiently long line of input will cause a buffer overflow with dire consequences, as this may constitute an exploitable flaw.

Note also that the syntax for parsing a scanset is `%99[^\n]`: no trailing `s` is required.

Comment: Hi chqrlie, I tried **"scanf("%99[^\n]", str);"**, but it didn't worked for me.


_enter the integer variable :5
enter the double variable :6.0
enter the string :integer variable is 5
float variable is 6.0
string variable is .N=ö_

Comment: @Anuj: did you add a space at the beginning of `" %99[^\n]"`? I do not see it in your comment. Without the space, the `scanf` fails and `str` is uninitialized, which is consistent with the garbage output you observe.

Comment: Hi chqrlie: yes I was not using space. Now it is working fine. Thanks a lot for your help (and detailed explanation).