# Why am I receiving junk when scanning into parallel arrays with differently calculated indexes?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

In this code I am asking for the first and last name for 5 students along with their grades.

I have tried removing the double array from the code and it outputs to console as expected; it is when I am taking input from the user for the character 2-dimensional array and double array in the same for loop that I have the junk output to the first two rows of the character 2-dimensional array. I am unsure why this happens, can someone explain please?

All input is being typed directly into the program.

[Output with junk Code below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vv9IH.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int size =5;
    char name[size*2][20];
    double grades[size];
    int check=0,i,j;
    printf("\nPlease input records of students (enter a new line after each record) as directed.\n\n");

    for(i=0;i<size*2;i+=2){
        printf("Firstname: ");
        scanf("%s",name[i]);

        printf("Lastname: ");
        scanf("%s",name[i+1]);

        printf("Grade: ");
        scanf("%lf",&grades[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    for(i=0;i<size*2;i+=2){
        printf("First Name: ");
        printf("%s",name[i]);
        printf(" | Last Name: ");
        printf("%s",name[i+1]);
        printf(" | Grade: %0.1lf\n",grades[i]);
    }
}
```

[Output without junk with double array being removed code below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I62Uv.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int size =5;
    char name[size*2][20];
    //double grades[size];
    int check=0,i,j;
    printf("\nPlease input records of students (enter a new line after each record) as directed.\n\n");

    for(i=0;i<size*2;i+=2){
        printf("Firstname: ");
        scanf("%s",name[i]);

        printf("Lastname: ");
        scanf("%s",name[i+1]);

        //printf("Grade: ");
        //scanf("%lf",&grades[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    for(i=0;i<size*2;i+=2){
        printf("First Name: ");
        printf("%s",name[i]);
        printf(" | Last Name: ");
        printf("%s\n",name[i+1]);
        //printf(" | Grade: %0.1lf\n",grades[i]);
    }
}
```

Using the solution the the question: [not able to read string after reading double data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40853105/not-able-to-read-string-after-reading-double-data-type) outputted the same junk as my [original code with junk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vv9IH.png).
[Example with linked solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77tQO.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int size =5;
    char name[size*2][20];
    double grades[size];
    int check=0,i,j;
    printf("\nPlease input records of students (enter a new line after each record) as directed.\n\n");

    for(i=0;i<size*2;i+=2){
        printf("Firstname: ");
        scanf(" %19[^\n]",name[i]);

        printf("Lastname: ");
        scanf(" %19[^\n]",name[i+1]);

        printf("Grade: ");
        scanf("%lf",&grades[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    for(i=0;i<size*2;i+=2){
        printf("First Name: ");
        printf("%s",name[i]);
        printf(" | Last Name: ");
        printf("%s",name[i+1]);
        printf(" | Grade: %0.1lf\n",grades[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you might find help here http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html , it is the source of all wisdom on what can go wrong with using scanf. If it does not help start debugging by NOT ignoring the return value.

Comment: At a guess the `\n` which, after scanning doubles, is left in the input is what causes your problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [not able to read string after reading double data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40853105/not-able-to-read-string-after-reading-double-data-type)

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not help @Yunnosch.
I will check your first link.

Comment: Please [edit] to explain why the proposed "Does this answer..." did not help. Then I will delete that proposal, but you would be likely to receive it (or something similar) again by others. (And you know, if three users agree on this, though wrong, your question is closed....). I propose to link to that answer and explain the differences (either inside the question or in a comment, probably better in the question itself).

Comment: You noted that the proposed dupe does not help and that it has the same junk result. I recommend however to be more detailed about how you tried that. I.e. show the code variant you tried to use that concept.

Comment: Please describe the input syntax/structure and give an example. I.e. do you type it in? Is it a text file you pipe in?

Comment: Your indexing is off. Try to loop like this `for(i=0;i<size;i++)` and access as `[i*2] ... [i*2+1] ... [i]`.

Comment: This fixed my problem. Can you post this as an answer so I can close this question? And thank you very much.

Comment: @Elementalwisp that counts as a typo question, there are a gazillion examples of writing into an array out of bounds. The correct fix would have been to use a `struct` instead of separate arrays and none of these issues would have arisen.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Sorry, but that is not a typo. It is an oversight in the construction of loops. Which only counts as a typo-like lapse of concentration once you have gotten through a thousand correctly implemented loops and know that leaving the safe `for(i=0; i<N;i++)` is a risk not to be taken.

Comment: I am pretty sure that by "All of this code is being typed directly into the program." you mean all input. Please [edit] to move that to a less prominent place and drop the bold formatting please.

Comment: @Yunnosch "unlikely to help future readers"

Comment: I think the problem is not rare and my answer WOULD be helpful. The obstacle might be to get those readers to actually FIND it. Maybe I can get OP to change title or something.

Comment: Elementalwisp, can I convince you to change the title to something which describes the problem you had in terms which makes this more findable for people with similar problems? I propose "Why am I receiving junk when scanning into parallel arrays with differently calculated indexes?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indexing is off.

Loop like this `for(i=0;i<size;i++)` and access as `[i*2] ... [i*2+1] ... [i]`.

Once you have gotten through a thousand correctly implemented loops you will know that leaving the safe `for(i=0; i<N;i++)` is a risk not to be taken.

Alternatively consider using an array of `struct`, which allows to always use the same index value, instead of having to do the risky index calculation.